# How to inject entire managed bean via @ManagedProperty annotation?

Tags: java, jsf, dependency-injection, jsf-2

I'm trying to inject entire JSF managed bean into another managed bean by means of `@ManagedProperty` annotation (very similar to [Possible to inject @ManagedBean as a @ManagedProperty into @WebServlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469365), but I'm injecting into a bean, not a servlet). This is what I'm doing:

```
@ManagedBean
public class Foo {
  @ManagedProperty(value = "#{bar}")
  private Bar bar;
}

@ManagedBean
public class Bar {
}
```

Doesn't work (JSF 2.0/Mojarra 2.0.3):

```
SEVERE: JSF will be unable to create managed bean foo when it is 
requested.  The following problems where found:
- Property bar for managed bean foo does not exist. Check that 
  appropriate getter and/or setter methods exist.
```

Is it possible at all or I need to do this injection programmatically via `FacesContext`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to add setters and getters

```
@ManagedBean
public class Foo {
  @ManagedProperty(value = "#{bar}")
  private Bar bar;
  //add setters and getters for bar
  public Bar getBar(){
      return this.bar;
  }
  public void setBar(Bar bar){
      this.bar = bar;;
  }
}
```

When the `FacesContext` will resolve and inject dependencies it will use setters injection so appropriate setters/getters should be there.otherwise it won't find the property

Comment: Just a note, for xhtml JSF translates _foo to getFoo and setFoo, for managed di you actually need get_foo and set_foo!

Comment: Other note> For only injection only a setter is required. Ref> http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/injecting-managed-beans-in-jsf-2-0/