# Get managed bean reference in another managed bean

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, managed

I try to get instance of managed bean in another managed bean thanks to this **BalusC** post : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/jsf-get-managed-bean-by-name)

With `findBean` method, it's great, I retrieve my bean but with `ManagedProperty` I can not get my bean.

My bean to inject is this one :

```
@ManagedBean(name="locale")
@SessionScoped
public class LocaleBean {

   private String locale;

   public String getLocale() {              
        return locale;
   }

   public void setLocale(String locale) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(new Locale(locale));      
        this.locale = locale;
   }

}
```

So when I call `LocaleBean locale = findBean("locale");` in my `login` bean it's work but :

```
@ManagedProperty("#{locale}") // OR localeBean, LocaleBean...
private LocaleBean locale;
```

doesn't work...

> com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Impossible de créer le bean géré «login».  Les problèmes suivants ont été détectés :
>        - La propriété «locale» du bean géré «login» n’existe pas.

Why please ?

Comment: is it because my `locale` bean may have not bean instantiated before `login` bean...?

Comment: I don't understand French very well but did you created getters and setters for this property?

Comment: I just saw this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165567/how-to-inject-entire-managed-bean-via-managedproperty-annotation. It's a getter/setter problem indeed. Thank you partlov

Comment: It'd be helpful for yourself (and others when posting it as a question!) if you reconfigure your environment to use English locale. If you search/google/share English error messages, you'll get more hits and quicker clues.

Comment: I will do that next time sorry. Thank you for your previous mentionned post BalusC

Answer (score 4):

you should write getter/setter for bean which is annotated @ManagedProperty

Answer (score 2):

I see that your LocaleBean is session scoped.
Instead of the @ManagedProperty annotation and the getters/setters, you can reference another session scoped managed bean directly from the code using the getSessionMap method of the servlet context:

```
LocaleBean locale = (LocaleBean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                    .getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("locale");
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to call LocaleBean in your Login bean needs to be SessionScoped or above.

If you want to call Locale Bean on Login Bean u have to do

```
@ManagedProperty("#{locale}")
private LocaleBean locale;
```

Call the appropriate set e get for that. 
You don't need this

```
LocaleBean locale = findBean("locale");
```

You can use now locale as it is local like this in your Login Bean:

```
String s = local.getLocale();
```