# get logged user name.(jsf 2)

Tags: jsf-2, authentication, session-scope

I have a session scoped bean  to manage my user login and also a login filter, but i'm not sure how to get the user object inside of another bean to show certain data based on the user who is logged in.

this is my Login Bean:

```
 @ManagedBean(name="user")
        @SessionScoped
        public class LoginBean {

            private String username;
            private String password;
            private UsuariosEntity current;

         public LoginBean(){}
        @EJB
        UsuariosDAO userService=new UsuariosDAO();



            public String login() {

           try{
           current = userService.buscar(username, password);

           System.out.println(current.getUsuario());
           }catch(Exception e){

           }
                if (current == null) {
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Unknown login, try again"));
                    return (username = password = null);
                } else {
                    return "/Contenido/vistaProcesos?faces-redirect=true";
                }
            }

            public String logout() {
                System.out.println("logout");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
                return "/Login?faces-redirect=true";
            }

            public boolean isLoggedIn() {
                return current != null;
            }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public UsuariosEntity getCurrent() {
            return current;
        }



    }
```

Login Filter:

```
@WebFilter("/Contenido/*")
public class FiltroLogin implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        LoginBean user = (LoginBean) req.getSession().getAttribute("user");

        if (user != null && user.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is logged in, so just continue request.
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            // User is not logged in, so redirect to index.
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/Login.jsf");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }


}
```

and this is what i want to do:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "procesos")
@ViewScoped
public class ProcesosBean implements Serializable {
    private List<VistaProcesosEntity> procesos;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){

          //i want to fill procesos List with data, depending of the user who is logged on.

       procesos=new ArrayList<VistaProcesosEntity>();

      /* LoginBean user; // i dont know from where should i get the user object.. 

       if (user.getCurrent().getTipo()=="Planta") {
        procesos= Procesos.getALL();
        }else if(user.getCurrent().getTipo()=="Exportadora"){
            procesos=Procesos.getALLbyExportadora(user.getCurrent().getUsuario());
        }  else if (user.getCurrent().getTipo()=="Productor"){
            procesos=Procesos.getALLbyProductor(user.getCurrent().getUsuario());
        } else{
           procesos= Procesos.getALL();
       }   */
    }

    public List<VistaProcesosEntity> getProcesos() {
        return procesos;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to inject entire managed bean via @ManagedProperty annotation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165567/how-to-inject-entire-managed-bean-via-managedproperty-annotation)

Comment: @user1462933: Is it intended to use plain JSF backing beans? You could really benefit from using CDI. In case you want to read more about it: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/jsf-backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930889/are-managedbeans-obsolete-in-javaee6-because-of-named-in-cdi-weld)

Comment: thanks Aquillo and Kolossus.. i'll look the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ManagedBean(name = "procesos")
@ViewScoped
public class ProcesosBean implements Serializable {
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{user}") // this references the @ManagedBean named user
    private LoginBean loginBean;

    private List<VistaProcesosEntity> procesos;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        UsariosEntity current = loginBean.getCurrent();
    }
}
```

I have extended your `ProcesosBean` a bit. Notice the referenced `LoginBean` and retrieving the `UsariosEntity` in the `init()` function. If you have any more questions or something isn't clear (enough), please ask.

Comment: thanks for your help..but it gives me an error now..

"com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: No se puede definir la propiedad procesos para el bean administrado procesos"

in english says something like "cannot define property procesos for the managed property procesos.

Comment: Ok, can you create a new question for this with the updated version of `ProcesosBean`? You can reference it here, I'd be happy to help you with it. Though due to the sake of future readability of Stackoverflow and its questions, a new question would be better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305825/com-sun-faces-mgbean-managedbeancreationexception-cannot-set-property-procesos ---> there is the new question :)