# How to run eager loaded Application scoped Bean with dependencies?

Tags: jsf-2.2

I´m starting my Bean when the application starts with the following Bean:

```
...
@ManagedBean(eager = true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class LoadBean implements Serializable {
...
```

It Works as expected, the problem is (I suppose) that dependencies used inside my Bean are not initialized. They are null when I´m going to use them.

```
...
    @ManagedProperty("#{pservice}")
    Pservice pservice

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() { 
        ...
        pservice.doSomething()    // Null pointer exception
        ...
    }

    public void setPservice(Pservice pservice) {
        this.pservice = pservice;
    }
...
```

How could I handle this? Is there a way to force the execution of the Bean when are the dependencies are ready? Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is `pservice.doSomething()`? Constructor, postconstruct, method?

Comment: @PostConstruct
public void init()

Comment: And have you defined the getters and setters for `pservice`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165567/how-to-inject-entire-managed-bean-via-managedproperty-annotation

Comment: Yes, the setter and getter are defined. I think the problem is the dependency instantiation. When I try to access to pservice methods, it returns null pointer exception because the dependency manager has not created an instance of pservice.